# MySQL case makes a new column

Tags: mysql, sql, case

If I use a MySQL case statement, it creates a new column, it didn't replace the column.

Is it possible to replace the column instead of new column?

Example:

```
SELECT *, 
       CASE WHEN housenumber_addition IS NULL THEN 'ABC' 
       ELSE housenumber_addition END AS housenumber_addition 
FROM customer
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible -- don't use `SELECT *`, list columns explicitly instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You select that column effectively twice, just like you can select any column a multiple times:

```
select housenumber_addition, housenumber_addition, housenumber_addition 
from customer
```

In general, you should select each column separately and replace `housenumber_addition` by the code you provided. [`SELECT *` is considered harmful anyways.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3639861/845034)

Comment: I'm not sure this directly addresses the OP, which is concerned with _not_ inadvertently selecting the `hostnumber_addition` column in _addition_ to the `CASE` expression.

Comment: Thanks!

I tried the first time with:
`SELECT housenumer_addition,
CASE WHEN housenumber_addition IS NULL THEN 'ABC' 
       ELSE housenumber_addition END AS housenumber_addition 
FROM customer`

And got the old and new column. My bad..

Answer (score 0):

Just explicitly select the columns you want to appear in your result set, and, in your case, *exclude* the `housenumber_addition` column:

```
SELECT
    col1,     -- some column, not housenumber_addition
    col2,     -- some other column, also not housenumber_addition
    ...,
    CASE WHEN housenumber_addition IS NULL
         THEN 'ABC' 
         ELSE housenumber_addition END AS housenumber_addition
FROM customer;
```

Note that your `CASE` expression doesn't serve much purpose, because you could have just used `COALESCE`:

```
COALESCE(housenumber_addition, 'ABC')
```